# What is the purpose of stopping actors in Akka?

Tags: akka, fault-tolerance

I have read the Akka [docs on fault tolerance & supervision](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/scala/fault-tolerance.html), and I *think* I totally get them, with one big exception (no pun intended).

**Why would you ever want/need to *stop* a child actor???**

The only clue in the docs is:

> Closer to the Erlang way is the strategy to just stop children when they fail and then take corrective action in the supervisor...

But to me, **stopping** a child is the same as saying "*don't execute this code any longer*", which to me, is effectively the same as deploying new changes to the code which has that actor removed entirely:

- Every Actor plays some critical role in the actor system
- To simply stop the actor means that actor currently doesn't have a role any longer, and presumes the system can now somehow (magically) work without it
- So again, to me, this is no different than refactoring the code to not even have the actor any more, and then deploying those changes

I'm sure I'm just not seeing the forest through the trees on this one, but I just don't see any use cases where I'd have this big complex actor system, where each actor does critical work and then hands it off to the next critical actor, but then I stop an actor, and magically the whole system keeps on working perfectly.

**In short: stopping an actor (to me) is like ripping the transmission out of a moving vehicle. How can this ever be a good/desirable thing?!?**

Comment: Someone always goes through and downvotes my Akka questions.  I feel like someone on Akka's user guide editorial team has a grudge against me because I call out areas where their docs need improving! **This question is on topic, is not a dupe, and is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Why the downvote?**

Comment: Baxter...is that you?!? At least have the courage to speak!

Comment: This definitely is a valid question and I can vouch for the Akka team that we have no reason or desire to downvote questions that call out omissions in our docs. But a better way to get them fixed is to open issues on github, I stumbled across this only by chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essence of the "error kernel" pattern is to delegate risky operations and protect essential state, it is common to spawn child-actors for one-off operations, and when that operation is completed and its result send off somewhere else, the child-actor or the parent-actor needs to stop it. (otherwise the child-actor will remain active/leak)

Comment: Thanks @Viktor Klang (+1) - this is an interesting answer, and I may decide to revert the green check (sorry znurgl). When you say "*otherwise the child-actor will remain active/leak*", what do you mean by **leak**? I assume we want to stop the child actor if it doesn't have any work to do (otherwise it's just taking up resources), but not sure what you mean by "leak" and am worried there's something big pertaining to the framework that I'm missing here. Thanks again!

Comment: Actors are alive until stopped, so if an actor will never have anything else to do, it needs to be stopped. Actors are stopped either manually, by supervision or when their parent-actor stops.

Answer (score 1):

If the child actor is doing a longer process that could be terminated safely, such as video coding, or some kind of file transformation and you have to deploy a new build, in that case a terminate sign would be useful to stop running processes gracefully.

Comment: OK, I *think* I get it. I think it's fair to say that *Stop* is sort of a special use case and would not be a normal part of the error handling life cycle (meaning, you wouldn't normally stop a child from inside a parent's `SupervisorStrategy#Decider`).

Answer (score 0):

> Every Actor plays some critical role in the actor system

This is where you are running into trouble, I can create a child actor to do a job, for example execute a query against a database or maintain the state of a connected user and this is its only purpose.

Once the database query is complete or the user has gracefully disconnected the child actor no longer has any role to play and should be stopped so that it will release any resources it holds.

> To simply stop the actor means that actor currently doesn't have a role any >longer, and presumes the system can now somehow (magically) work without it

The system is able to continue because I can create new child actors if/when they are needed.